# Manage child component visibility by parent focus in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search input component in React, which also has a lot of options. I want the options box to appear when the input is focused, or while there's interaction in the box. This box should disappear when something outside of either search input of the box is being focused. So, it behaves like a pretty standard behavior.

There is a problem that I'm not sure how to solve. Some of the actions inside the options box cause another component to be rendered inside the box, so the focus is being lost (the browser focuses the `<body>`). My component thinks that it means to hide the options box.

I found a fix for that - I only hide the box if the `blur` of the container was caused by something from outside of it. It works correctly in some cases. But there's a problem when, let's say, there's a button causing the options box to render something else, making the button itself disappear. The focus goes to the `<body>` and I can no longer hide the options box without manually focusing on the search input and then focusing out.

Are there some techniques to manage visibility per real or pseudo focus? In perfect scenario, I'd like to avoid programatically focusing my element in, for two reasons:

1. I'd like the `autofocus` attribute to work correctly.
2. There are really a lot of components in a tree for the options box - making them all focus back programatically would mean a lot of repetitive code.

For simplicity, I removed the props and elements irrelevant to the question. But there's quite a bit going on for the `<OptionsBox />`.

Here's my simplified component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import OptionsBox from './OptionsBox';

export default function Search() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const [showOptions, setShowOptions] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div
            tabIndex={-1}
            onFocus={() => setShowOptions(true)}
            onBlur={event => {
                const isChildFocused = event.currentTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget);

                if (!isChildFocused) {
                    setShowOptions(false);
                }
            }}
        >
            <input
                type="text"
                value={value}
                onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)}
            />
            {showOptions && (
                <OptionsBox />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get some workaround to work on this issue and find it this way (in the link).

- `Autofocus` parent wrapper (depends on requirement).
- `track the click event`. If it is inside, then keep the focus else, blur the `<OptionBox />`

---

###### Here is the change that I have done

- Added `ref` to `parentDiv` and passed it to `<OptionBox/>` for tracking
- Added `2 buttons` for testing `onClick` `focus` events

  - `1st` onCLick for focusing `body`
  - `2nd` onClick to focus `input` within `<Parent/>` / `<OptionBox/>`
- I added a `clickHandler` to check, if the `element` you are trying to focus on is within `parentDiv`, if so, then keep the `focus` else `blur` it and `setState` to `false`.

*Not sure about the Efficiency of this solution but you can try this (if already haven't tried it) as it totally depends on the use case.*

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-hypatia-4mu2x?file=/src/OptionBox.js